# How do I insert a constantly changing (dynamic) string from a text document into .conkyrc as an image path

Tags: bash, grep, conky

I want to change the Clementine album art with each song. Essentially, I am trying to insert an image path in Conky that changes every few seconds.

I have a script `clementine.sh` that runs every 5 seconds in Conky using this line:

```
${execi 5 sh ~/.config/openbox/conky/clementine.sh}
```

The script runs the following command:

```
qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.GetMetadata | grep arturl | cut -c16- > ~/.config/openbox/conky/image
```

What this does, is it finds the `arturl` from Clementine, trims it, and places it in the file `image`. The line overwrites each time. The line that is written looks like this:

```
/tmp/clementine-art-ED9078.jpg
```

What I would like to do, is find a way to copy the line `/tmp/clementine-art-ED9078.jpg` from the file `image` and place it in my .conkyrc file in the line:

```
${image "xxxx" -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

Where the `xxxx` is, is where I want the text to write to, so that the line:

```
${image "xxxx" -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

Will actually look like:

```
${image /tmp/clementine-art-ED9078.jpg -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

Obviously, the line will change with each song.

I am wanting to do this with a script (or directly in Conky, etc.), and not have to install any programs or anything to accomplish this. I believe it is "do-able", I just don't have a clue how to do it. I have scoured the Internet and came up with nothing I can use. Any help anyone can give me will not only be appreciated, it will make my headache go away.

Note:
I am able (from Conky) to list artist, title, and album using the following lines in .conkyrc:

```
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}${execi 5 qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.GetMetadata | grep artist}

${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}${execi 5 qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.GetMetadata | grep title}

${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}${execi 5 qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.GetMetadata | grep album}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using soft links

In your `~/.conkyrc` file, add the line:

```
${image /tmp/conky.jpg -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

After the `qdbus` line in your script, add the line:

```
ln -sf "$(cat ~/.config/openbox/conky/image)" /tmp/conky.jpg
```

This `ln` command updates the link file `/tmp/conky.jpg` to point to whatever image file name is in the `~/.config/openbox/conky/image` file.

To get the behavior that you want, you may want to experiment with two flags on the conky `image` line: `-n` tells conky not to cache the image while `-f interval` to specifies conky's cache flush interval for that image.

#### Using `awk`

To summarize, the name of your image file is in `~/.config/openbox/conky/image` and you want to transfer it to your `~/.conkyrc` file.  So, after the `qdbus` line in your script, add the line:

```
awk -v "img=$(cat ~/.config/openbox/conky/image)" '/image/{sub("xxxx", img)} 1' ~/.conkyrc.in >~/.conkyrc
```

where `~/.conkyrc.in` is your prototype conkyrc file, the one that contains the line:

```
${image xxxx -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

The awk command replaces the xxxx with the name of your image file.  After the `awk` command is run, a new `~/.conkyrc` file is created with the correct image name.

How it works:

- `-v "img=$(cat ~/.config/openbox/conky/image)"`

  This creates an `awk` variable `img` and assigns to it the contents of `~/.config/openbox/conky/image`.
- `/image/{sub("xxxx", img)}`

  This looks for lines containing the word `image`.  For any line containing that word, the first occurrence of `xxxx` is replaced with the value of variable `img`.
- `1`

  This cryptic command just tells awk to print every line it receives from the input file.
- `~/.conkyrc.in`

  This is input file, the one containing the dummy `${image xxxx ....` line.
- `>~/.conkyrc`

  This tells the shell to redirect the output of `awk` to the your conkyrc file, overwriting the previous copy.

#### Using `m4`  (Advanced)

Create the file `~/.conkyrc.m4` which looks just like your normal conky file except that it contains the line:

```
${image translit(include(/home/user/.config/openbox/conky/image), [
])) -p 0,620 -s 75x75}
```

Then, run:

```
m4 ~/.conkyrc.m4 >~/.conkyrc
```

`m4` will recognize `translit` and `include` as commands that it should obey.  When it sees the `include` command, it will read your `~/.config/openbox/conky/image` and include the contents.  That file will likely have a trailing new line character.  The `translit` command is there to remove that newline.

`m4` is a very powerful macro language that you can use to manage many parts of your conkyrc file.  If you don't want to take the time to learn a new language, it is probably simpler to stick to the `awk` solution.

Comment: I used your first answer with the -n flag and it worked beautifully. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: I used the above solution (soft link) like this:
1) make the soft link with:
{execi 15 ln -sf "$(cat path_to_text_file_with_image_path.txt)" /tmp/conky.jpg}
and after that 2) ${image /tmp/conky.jpg -p 0,620 -s 75x75}